# Opening cursor to fetch and update column values of a table based on other column values of same table in oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, sql-update, oracle12c, database-cursor

I have to update last 2 columns in a table based on below logic, which has 42 columns.

- Field Value of C42( which is substituted for N in below equation) = ("First column position with a null/no value" - 1)
- Field Value of C41  = Field Value of column C(N) , where N = (value of column “C42” Minus 1)

Note: Table values are set-up in a way that, when the first null value is encountered in a column; other columns following are null for sure in any particular record.Table has some 100K records and it's a intermediate table where above calculation repeats every week and new values are populated in the table and again the last two columns are to be calculated every week.

eg:

```
C42 = C19   ( 20 - 1) 

C41 = C(20) when 20 columns have some value and 21st column is null
```

Tried to create a stored procedure and opened a cursor to fetch the values for calculation, but having issues with creating the logic and updating each row based on the logic. Can someone suggest an efficient way to perform the above calculation logic and to update every record. Thanks in advance

Comment: It isn't really clear. Can you try to explain the logic more clearly, and shows some examples with representative values (but fewer columns - maybe an MCVE with say 10 columns to demonstrate)? I think you are setting one to the column position, and the other to the value in that column, for the last non-null in that row...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand what you are doing, you don't need PL/SQL, you just need a simple update using coalesce and a case expression - admittedly, both with lots of terms so it's a bit unwieldy.

Using a much-simplified table with only four columns to worry about, plus the 41st and 42nd you want to update:

```
create table your_table (c1 number, c2 number, c3 number, c4 number, c41 number, c42 number);
insert into your_table (c1, c2) values (11, 12);
insert into your_table (c1, c2, c3) values (23, 24, 25);
```

You can get the `c42` value by coalescing all of the other columns in reverse order:

```
coalesce(c4, c3, c2, c1)
```

or in your case:

```
coalesce(c40, c39, c38, c37, ..., c4, c3, c2, c1)
```

And you can get the position of that column with a case expression like:

```
case
  when c40 is not null then 40
  when c39 is not null then 39
  ...
  when c4 is not null then 4
  when c3 is not null then 3
  when c2 is not null then 2
  when c1 is not null then 1
end;
```

You can query just to see the values with (using my simplified table):

```
select c1, c2, c3, c4,
  coalesce(c4, c3, c2, c1) as c41,
  case
    when c4 is not null then 4
    when c3 is not null then 3
    when c2 is not null then 2
    when c1 is not null then 1
  end as c42
from your_table;

        C1         C2         C3         C4        C41        C42
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
        11         12                               12          2
        23         24         25                    25          3
```

And you can update with just:

```
update your_table
set c41 = coalesce(c4, c3, c2, c1),
  c42 =
    case
      when c4 is not null then 4
      when c3 is not null then 3
      when c2 is not null then 2
      when c1 is not null then 1
    end;

2 rows updated.

select * from your_table;

        C1         C2         C3         C4        C41        C42
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
        11         12                               12          2
        23         24         25                    25          3
```

If this is something you're going to be doing regularly then you could make those virtual columns instead, so they're calculated automatically and always up-to-date.

Comment: Thanks for your time and effort. I had to find second not null value for C41, however used your logic and tweaked a bit for my solution and it worked.